# Firebug Not working after updating Firefox 14.0.1 (inspect element does not display HTML)

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, firebug

Firebug stops working after auto-updating of Mozilla Firefox V 14.0.1.

I have updated my Firebug but it's still not working. "Inspect Element" does not display HTML.

Comment: Well, what does "not working" mean? Any errors? What system? What have you tried? Note also that this is not a tech support forum; this is a site for programming questions.

Comment: inspect element  do not display HTML

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the solution

Firebug stops working after auto updating of Mozilla firefox V 14.0.1 I have updated my Firebug but still it's not working As you can follow the steps to star you firebug inspect element do not work

Just following the following step’s

Open the following link

[http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/addons/1843/)

or for win 32

http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/win32/xpi/

Download firebug-1.10.0b4-fx.xpi 12-Jul-2012 05:25 1.5M

Or Latest verson

Save on Hard disk 
Open download file with fire fox 
Click on Install 
And FireBug is Again for you to again Play with web....:)

And it works for me

For more information view following link.

http://ooolu.com/Seva/FireIssue.aspx/

Comment: For me, Firebug did not come up at all when pressing F12, there was also no toolbar. This solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: 404 could you please explain the solution or maybe post a new link?

Answer (score 0):

Check Firebug's compatibility table on their [page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and make sure your version is compatible with your version of Firefox.